# Interop files not registered due to difference in program installation

Tags: c#

I have a program which references the libraries found in a third party's program's program file directory under the c drive. The program works on all computers where the third-party software is installed as long as it is under the c drive. However my issue is that the machine where I need to run this program has the third part software installed under the d drive.
Under the "release" folder in my project directory, the required DLLs come as "interop". I'm not entirely familiar with how these interop DLLs work, but apparently they are not registered on the machine with the program installed under the D drive. 
My question is, how do I make the program run independently of install path of the third party program?

Comment: Never, *never*, **never** register an interop library.  You really do have to install the native COM component onto the target machine.  Use the vendor or author's installer is pretty much required if you have no real idea what files need to be copied and what registry keys need to be written.  Use a telephone and ask them for a merge module.

Comment: @HansPassant I do know what files need to be used. The native COM components are installed onto the target machine, however I'm not sure why they're still coming up as unregistered.